# Java - what's the difference between 2 little codes

Tags: java, math, output

Can someone explain to me why the result of the codes below is different? Thanks in advance. All the variables are double.

First:

```
volume=(4/3)*(Math.PI*Math.pow(raio,3))
```

if I declare that raio=5, the result will be=392,xxx

The result will also be 392 if:

```
volume=(Math.PI*Math.pow(raio,3))*(4/3);
```

Second:

```
volume=(Math.PI*Math.pow(raio,3))*4/3;
```

if I declare that raio=5, the result will now be correct: 523,xxx

Comment: 4 and 3 aren't doubles.

Comment: My guess is this has to do something with types. what if you make 4 a double and write (4.0/3)?

Comment: Look closer at the order of operations

Comment: @Montaldo Thanks. You're right, i was missing the ".0" afther the "4".  Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because when you use:

```
volume=(Math.PI*Math.pow(raio,3))*(4/3);
```

What happens is (4/3) is evaluated as integer division, so (4/3) = 1.

Thus,

```
volume=(Math.PI*Math.pow(raio,3))*4/3;
```

would work because it's a double * 4, which is a double, then divided by 3, which is also a double.

If you try this:

```
volume=(Math.PI*Math.pow(raio,3))*(4.0/3.0);
```

You should see it work.

Note that you probably can get away with just 4.0/3 or just 4/3.0 .

Comment: Thanks! Nice and simple answer. I got it now. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: No problem. That's what we're here for.

Answer (score 1):

```
(pi * raio^3)*(4/3) != (pi * raio^3)*4 / 3.
```

In the second one, it's multiplying by 4, THEN dividing by 3. In the first one, it's multiplying by (4/3)

Not to mention 4 and 3 aren't doubles

Answer (score 1):

In the first calculation you effectively run 1*(Math.PI*Math.pow(raio,3)) as 4/3 is done in integers and evaluated to 1. in the second calculation, the first argument is evaluated to double, causing the rest of the expression to be evaluated as double. Try to run (4.0/3.0)*(Math.PI*Math.pow(raio,3))

Answer (score 1):

In you first case, `(4/3) returns an int which is 1;`

Use `MathExpression*(4.0/3.0);`

Answer (score 1):

Math.PIS is defined double PI = 3.141592653589793;

when you perform any operation where one variable is double, the other one is auto promoted to double. The difference in your two examples is coming because of segment 4/3.

When used in braces, it's treated as int and results into 1, while in the other example, 4 gets multiplied to a double value to result into double and then getting ddivided by 3 which results as 1.333333.

In summary: `volume=(Math.PI*Math.pow(raio,3))*(4/3);` evaluated as

```
        volume = (392.6990816987241)*(4/3)
        volume = (392.6990816987241) * (1)  //<--int division
        volume = 392.6990816987241
```

while `volume=(Math.PI*Math.pow(raio,3))*4/3;` gets evaluated as

```
        volume = (392.6990816987241) *4/3
        volume = 1570.7963267948965/3   //division of double by int
        volume = 523.5987755982989
```

If you notice, the second result is `1.33333` times first result.

If in the first example, if you change one argument as double e.g. 4.0 or 3.0 or both i.e.

```
        volume=(Math.PI*Math.pow(raio,3))*(4.0/3)
   or   volume=(Math.PI*Math.pow(raio,3))*(4/3.0)
   or   volume=(Math.PI*Math.pow(raio,3))*(4.0/3.0)
```

you will get the same result as in example 2.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

First, look at this precedence table: http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~palsetia/java/precedenceTable.html

Precedence decides which expression will be resolved to a value before others. In the first and second examples you have given:

- the brace containing pi will be resolved for itself
- the brace with the expression `4/3` will be resolved for itself

The later division yields `1` since the division of two `int`eger literals results in an `int`eger type which cannot represent decimals. Those decimals are lost in the computations of both the first and second example.

In contrast to that, the last expression resolves from left to right. The braces do not effect the order of computation since they enclose the first expression which would be resolved first anyways. This first brace results in a `double` type which is then multiplied with the `int` `4`. What happens here is called an [**implicit conversion**](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#Implicit_type_conversion)

This actually is a special form of implicit conversion called a **type promotion**. In order to combine an `int` and a `double`, Java first *upgrades* the `int` to a `double` to make the types compatible. `double` can in a way be seen as a more general type than `int`. The same happens one step later when the result of the former computation is divided by the `int` `3`.

Because the implicit conversion occurs before any `int`eger values are divided, the decimals of `4/3` are preserved what results in another result than in the first two examples. In those examples, you could use an **explicit conversion** to get the desired result:

```
(double) 4/3
```

Note that the explicit conversion - the statement that looks like a type casting - has a higher precedence than the division, i.e. `4` will first be converted to an `double` before this double is divided by `3` what preceeds another implicit conversion of this number to a `double` type. Of course, you could also use a double literal `4d` instead of the explicit conversion and observe the same result.

PS: the second and first examples also contain an implicit conversion of the result of `4/3` when it is multiplied with the result of the other brace containing pi. At this time, the decimals are however already lost.